# Can't get Google Font to show up for HTML email in Gmail

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, webfonts

Title explains the issue, but I can't get a Google Font to show up in Gmail for an HTMl email template that I created. I've tried to figure out how to do so (inline CSS, @import, @font-face, etc.) but it still won't show up.

Is there currently a way to get Google Fonts to show up in Gmail if you're using an HTML email template? I know there must be, but I'm really stuck here and would appreciate any help! Here's my current code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster"/>

<style type="text/css"> h1 { position: relative; font-family: 'Lobster', sans-serif; font-size:330%; } </style>

<h1 style="position: relative; text-align: center; font-family: 'Lobster'; padding: 1%;">Heading</h1>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Gmail (like most webmail) strips header styles, and there's no way to inline custom font declarations. Email has so many more constraints than the web because of the many and different ways the HTML is consumed and altered by clients.

You'll need to inline your CSS and use font stacks that fall back to acceptable system fonts, and if you absolutely require a font for a certain look, do what's taboo on the web: use images, but keep them small. The alt text will ensure that your plain text version is readable, too.

Comment: Sorry for the late response from me - thanks a ton for clarifying. Think this answers my questions for now :)

Comment: Hey @denmch, I came across this article, and it seems as though GMail does support header styles. Any idea why they're not working now? https://emails.hteumeuleu.com/troubleshooting-gmails-responsive-design-support-ad124178bf81

Comment: It looks like Gmail started rolling out support for embedded styles in September, and Litmus has been keeping up with the updates here: https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-to-support-responsive-email-design

Comment: I have to support a wide range of email clients, so I use a limited set of the most widely supported styles and inline everything using Campaign Monitor's inliner tool (https://inliner.cm/ -- it works better than Mailchimp's in my experience). There are always going to be clients or webmail interfaces that mangle or ignore your code, and inlining styles is the best way to get them all to understand your intent.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, and that's a really cool tool. Thanks for showing me that. One last question if you have the time - I do really want to use a custom font in the header, so I'm considering having it be an image. However, I need part of the text to link to my website. I know that PDF's support embedding hyperlinks in the image, but they are not supported on Mail Chimp. Is there a type of image that I can use that would be supported and allows me to hyperlink a portion of the image's text?

Comment: I've never tried to use an image map, but if you search you can find information on using images maps in email. I think the normal compromise, and it's easy to accomplish, is to wrap the entire image in a hyperlink. If it's designed in such a way that one part serves as an obvious call to action or looks like something clickable (e.g., a button or a link), then it will work when people click it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. I'll just wrap the line of text as a whole. Thanks a ton for helping! Really appreciate it.